# Apache vhosts on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, localhost, virtualhost

I managed to set up virtual hots on my local machine, but I kinda run into a wall now.

Normally, when you type **localhost/** into browser you will see what you are supposed to see. But after I have set my virtual hosts, anything I type goes to the vhost. I cant figure a way to have a virtual host AND the old functionality together.

Here is my vhost file (btw, I am using xampplite)

```
<VirtualHost domain.eu>
    ServerName domain.eu
     DocumentRoot /www/domain

     ServerAlias *.domain.eu
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain.sk>
    ServerName domain.sk
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>
```

The second one gets redirected to **sk.domain.eu** via htaccess. When I add these 3 lines to vhosts, localhost starts working, but even the other vhosts go to **/www/**

```
<VirtualHost localhost>
    DocumentRoot /www
</VirtualHost>
```

But to comment/uncomment these 3 lines everytime I need to localhost is stupid. Any advice how can I keep both of them working together?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this before the `VirtualHost` containers:

```
NameVirtualHost localhost
NameVirtualHost domain.sk
NameVirtualHost domain.eu
```

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't be using domain names in the VirtualHost declarations.

If these three virtual hosts have different IP address, you should be putting their respective IP addresses into the VirtualHost blocks, and never mention NameVirtualHost.

If they use the same IP address, you must be using NameVirtualHost, and then you must, in each virtual host, repeat the name in the very same spelling that you did in the NameVirtualHost declaration.